# select enum in spring framwework

Tags: java, spring, select, enums

I've just started using spring framework and I've found a problem inserting data into the database.
Entering an itinerary I have a name, difficulty (enumeration).
My enum Difficolty

```
public enum Difficolty {

facile("facile"), media("media"), difficile("difficile");

private String name;

private Difficolty(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

My class Itinerary

```
public class Itinerary {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Difficolty difficolty;

..get/set method
```

And the form.jsp:

```
<div>
    <label for=id>Difficolty</label>
<div>

<form:select path="difficolty" class="form-control">
<form:option items="0" value="0" label="Seleziona difficoltà" />
<form:options items="${difficolty}" value="${id}" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>

</div>
</div>
```

Finally, in the jdbc implementation I have the "insert" method with

```
 //connection, prepareStateent and query... 
 ps.setString(1, itinerary.getName());                      
 ps.setString(2, itinerary.getDifficolty().toString());
```

why can not I get the select value? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the form selection empty?

Comment: I can predict all the fields of the enumeration by value () the problem comes when I click on "send"